# Show query results in CrystalReportViewer

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I in my winform write this code to show my_table content in a crystalReportviewer but nothing are shown:

```
private void Form10_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\bank.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from my_table", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
            rd.Load("CrystalReport2.rpt");
            rd.SetDataSource(dt);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
            crystalReportViewer1.Show();
        }
```

what is the problem?

Comment: also mentioned the error you found...thanks

Comment: I have no error but crystalReport is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
Check that your load method is getting the full path of the report,if not then use
rd.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport2.rpt")) and change your programming like i
mentioned.

private void Form10_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\bank.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from my_table", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
            rd.Load("CrystalReport2.rpt");
            rd.SetDataSource(dt);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
            rd.Refresh();
            this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
        }
I think it will help for you.
```

Comment: crystal report is empty yet

Comment: use stopper or debugger and check your each line of code.Or use try{} catch(){} block to for getting the error's first..